# Crash when sending exception through RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I'm starting to use RXAndroid and I've released my first beta with it and I got an exception I wasn't expecting. I'm certain it comes from my lack of understanding of the how the `onError` method works.

My code is like this:

```
disposables.add(Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<String> e) throws Exception {
                        if (e.isDisposed()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        //do stuff
                        if (stuff didn't fail) {
                            e.onNext(myString);
                        } else {
                            e.onError(new Exception("stuff failed"));
                        }
                        e.onComplete();
                    }


                })
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(@NonNull String myString) {
                                //do stuff

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                                //handle the error
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {
                            }
                        })
        );
```

I am getting a crash here:

`e.onError(new Exception("stuff failed"));`

But personally I thought this would handle that case?

```
public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
    //handle the error
}
```

I've already changed my code to handle this in a different way but I would still like to know how `onError` is supposed to work.

Thank you.

EDIT: The exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: stuff failed
       at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onError(ObservableCreate.java:83)
       at MyClass$4.subscribe(MyClass.java:295)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
       at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by java.lang.Exception: stuff failed
       at MyClass$4.subscribe(MyClass.java:295)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
       at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Include the exception stack trace

Comment: @Kiskae I've added the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between checking `e.isDisposed()` and your call to `e.onError()` the emitter ends up being disposed somehow. This causes the call to `onError` to fall back on the global error handler.

You need to check `e.isDisposed()` again or if you're willing to use experimental features RxJava 2.1.1 adds the `e.tryOnError` method which does not fall back if it is disposed already.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'm guessing it is still possible that if I check `isDisposed()` that it could still be disposed after that check and before calling `onError()` even if that is the very next call. So I probably need to find a better solution for this. Is what I'm doing not normal or not the correct way to do it?

Comment: In theory there is always a possibility that an error might happen (hence why `tryOnError` was added), if that solution is maintained then it is a choice between a "result" exception calling `onError` while an exception that does not matter outside of the lifecycle uses `tryOnError`